# Weird parsing json response via django-template

Tags: python, json, django, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to parse json response from get request to rest api.
Let me show you what i mean "weird".

My **views.py**

```
def about_abc(request, host_id):
    response = requests.get(
        'abc.net:1768/abc/api/v1/about',
        verify='cert/cacerts.pem',
        headers={'Accept': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'},
    ).json()
    context = {'response': response}
    return render(request, 'itpassed/about.html', context)
```

now, when i put i template **about.html**

```
{{ response }}
```

in web-browser i get normal, not parsed response (at least it looks like this)

```
{'version': '3.3.2', 'level': 'SP2', 'system': 'unix', 'server_time': '1556275198000', 'server_utc': '2', 'multinode_enabled': 'NO', 'cg_enabled': 'NO', 'instance_id': 'hostname'}
```

but when i put in **about.html**

```
{% if response %}
    {% for id in response %}
        <p>{{ id }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p>No IDs are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

i get ids without values:

```
version

level

system

server_time

server_utc

multinode_enabled

cg_enabled

instance_id
```

According to what i see in browser with only {{ response }} in template, whole response is passed (ids and their values).
How to parse this to look more or less like this:

```
version: 3.3.2

level: SP2

system: unix

server_time: 1556275198000

server_utc: 2

multinode_enabled: NO

cg_enabled: NO

instance_id: hostname
```

Comment: `{% for id in response %}` iterates dictionary keys. It would in regular Python, too. You need to look into iterating dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the key and value from template with:

```
{% if response %}
    {% for key,value in response.items %}
        <p>{{ key }}: {{ value }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p>No IDs are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: i edited it like this: `<p>{{ id }}: {{ response.id }}</p>` but only ":" was aded to ids. seems like there is nothing like response.id

Comment: i just exactly did this seconds ago :) thanks for your answer because this guided me to this anyway :)